# Single word with same meaning as phrase: "Power goes to head"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking to replace the `[]` in the sentence:

> The regime is showing signs of [power going to their heads].

Namely, I would like to use a single word, or two at most. A scientific-sounding noun would be great. Or if there is no such noun, I would still like to see what is the closest we can get.

I originally considered "autocracy," but it has only a loose connection with power going to heads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regime is showing signs of ***megalomania***

> **NOUN** obsession with the exercise of power.

Comment: Oh, that's actually a word. I thought it was just an incubus song! Good one.

Answer (score 0):

**Complacency**: (disapproving) a feeling of calm satisfaction with your own abilities or situation that prevents you from trying harder.
[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/complacency)

Answer (score 0):

**Arrogance** (noun)
**Arrogant** (adjective): unpleasantly proud and behaving as if you are more important than, or know more than, other people
[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/arrogant?q=arrogance)